# PHP session variables don't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, variables

Everytime I start a new session with login script, the session variables don't work.  On the login page, if I set a session variable like this: `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row_sql['id'];` it works, but passing on to other pagea doesn't.

I have also noted that the address link changes the domain, with "www.domain.com" becoming just domain.com, but now I've made my .htaccess file force it to redirect to www.domain.com. However checking my hosting provider I realized that the domain is shown as "domain.com". So, in one way or another, the session variables are not passing to other pages on the site.

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

My login script:

```
<?php

include ("../../connect/connect.php");

$email = $_POST['email']; $pass= base64_encode($_POST['pass']);

$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from users where email = '$email' and pass= '$pass' and status = 1"); 
$total_sql = mysqli_num_rows($sql); 
$row_sql = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

if($total_sql==0) { 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("incorrect email or password."); window.location.href = "index.php"</script>';       
    exit;   
} 
@session_start(); 
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row_sql['id']; 
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $row_sql['name']; 
$_SESSION['user_account'] = $row_sql['account']; 
$_SESSION['user_email'] = $row_sql['email'];

if(($row_sql['account']==1) || ($row_sql['account']==2)){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "../admin/index.php"</script>';
        exit; }elseif($row_sql['account']==3){  
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "../1/index.php"</script>';
        exit;
}

?>
```

All the other pages start like this and give the error "Notice: Undefined index: user_id in /home/black521/public_html/d/1/index.php on line 8"

```
<?php 
@session_start();
//-->
error_reporting(-1);
//-->
include ("../../connect/connect.php");
//--> 
$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Comment: Because there's a redirect.

Comment: check your .htaccess file for redirects.

Comment: "Everytime that Im starting a new session with login script", okay, let's start there. can you show us what your code looks like at that point? it's hard to guess what's going wrong with this little information

Comment: Login script included